# The meaning of 肉niuniu的

Tags: meaning

"肉niuniu的" is written as is and the person is describing/eating a durian 榴莲
Is it 扭扭? Or an onomatopoeia? or something else 
[image]

edit: added image for clarification
it's really "niuniu"

Comment: are you sure it is not 溜溜/liūliū/ (slippery)? Slippery( adj): (of a surface or object) difficult to hold firmly or stand on because it is smooth, wet, or slimy. 肉溜溜的 (meaty and slimy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an onomatopoeia. It doesn't have a special meaning. It just sounds **cutie and girly** here. I'd expect the speaker is a young girl.

Note: I can't see the image posted by OP.

Comment: You guessed right. It's a young girl talking

Answer (score 1):

The pronunciation does not sound right. It could be "liuliu" instead. "肉liuliu的" - 肉**溜溜**的 means 肉多又潤滑順口.